# How to make recyclerview layout views according to their count, horizontally and vertically?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make recyclerview react to the count of items and lay them out, in a different way occurding to the items count

I looked into 
[flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)  
but I couldn't achieve what I wanted using it.

the expected behavior I want is
if items `count` :

`in case 1`: the item fill the recyclerview

`in case 2`: the items align horizontally

`in case 3`: one item fill vertically half the parent, and the other two each take vertically half the other horizontal half of the parent.

`in case 4`: like grid layout, each item take half of the vertical and horizontal space.

`case 1`

[image: nothing]

`case 2`

[image: nothing]

`case 3`

[image: nothing]

`case 4`

[image]

`case 5`

[image]

Thanks for the help in advances.

Comment: It's a staggered recyclerview layout.

Comment: are your items limited to a maximum number of 4 items?

Comment: @Fartab the limit is 6 items, I edited the question to illustrate the fifth case

Comment: You can use staggeredLayoutManager for recyclerview.